# sort 2d numpy array lexicographically

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a large 2d array with hundreds of columns. I would like to sort it lexicographically, i.e. by first column, then by second column, and so on until the last column. I imagine this should be easy to do but I haven't been able to find a quick way to do this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what [`numpy.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) is for, but the interface is awkward. Pass it a 2D array, and it will argsort the *columns*, sorting by the *last* row first, then the second-to-last row, continuing up to the first row:

```
>>> x
array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
       [3, 1, 3, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 1, 3, 1]])
>>> numpy.lexsort(x)
array([4, 1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int64)
```

If you want to sort by rows, with the first column as the primary key, you need to rotate the array before `lexsort`ing it:

```
>>> x[numpy.lexsort(numpy.rot90(x))]
array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
       [3, 1, 1, 3, 1],
       [3, 1, 3, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Great this seems to work! So then I need to do searchsorted in this but not sure how to. So given a 1d array I want to find out if if it's one of the 2d array's sorted rows. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @grigor: maybe *[all(row == t) for row in x]*

Comment: One could add that there's a more time-efficient way of getting the same result as with `rot90`, by using `x[numpy.lexsort(x.T[::-1])]`. According to `timeit`, this is about 25% faster than `x[numpy.lexsort(numpy.rot90(x))]` (tested for `x.shape == (1000,5)`).