# Finding a numpy mode vector

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array of one-hot vectors.  I want to find the mode of these one-hot vectors.  Note that this is not equivalent to finding the mode over the values.

e.g. for

```
x = [[0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,1,0],
     [0,1,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0]]

assert vector_mode(x) == [0,0,0,1]
assert scipy.stats.mode(x) == [0,0,0,0]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this with numpy/scipy?

Comment: Why the extra set of parens?

Comment: I wanted my list brackets to line up.  =c)

Comment: The expected output is all zeros, right? Are you finding mode per col?

Comment: no, the expected output is `[0,0,0,1]`

Comment: @Divakar Per row

Comment: neither.  I'm finding the mode of the vectors.  The vector `[0,0,0,1]` is the most common one.

Comment: @Scott. That's what per-row means in this case :)

Comment: Well, `scipy.stats.mode` has an option `axis` to specify by-row or by-column.  They both give all `0`s.

Comment: We want to find the modal row, not the mode within each row or the mode within each column.

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: You'll probably end up having to [lexsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277143/sort-2d-numpy-array-lexicographically) it and find the longest run of equal rows.

Comment: The key here is that these are one-hot vectors. Makes life muuuuch easier.

Comment: Oh, right, one-hot. That simplifies things.

Comment: While we're on the topic, I'd like to point out that `scipy.stats.mode` has a [loop in it](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L436-L437) that compares every value found in the array to the entire array, which can cause surprisingly bad performance for an array with a lot of distinct values in it. For example, `scipy.stats.mode(range(10**5))` is appallingly slow.

Comment: scipy.stats.mode is quadratic?  what a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are dealing with `one-hot` vectors as rows of the `2D` input array. So, argmax of each row would be unique to each one-hot vector. Get those. Then, get their counts. Anyone of the rows with the max argmax count would be the desired mode row output. Let's pick the first off those with one more use of `argmax` and finally index into `2D` input.

Hence, one implementation -

```
idx = np.argmax(x,1)
count = np.bincount(idx)
out = x[(idx==count.argmax()).argmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your vectors are one-hot, you can just use [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the index of the hotspot and compute the mode of those:

```
hot = np.argmax(x, axis=1)
mode = scipy.stats.mode(hot).mode
```

In this case, `mode` is `3`, meaning that the most common vector has a hotspot in index `3`.

If you want to reinstate this into a one-hot vector, you can do:

```
vec = np.zeros(4)
vec[mode] = 1
```