# Tuple-like (lexographical) max in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I find myself running into the following situation in numpy muliple times over the past couple of months, and I cannot imagine there is not a proper solution for it.

I have a 2d array, let's say

```
x = np.array([
 [1, 2, 3],
 [2, -5, .333],
 [1, 4, 2],
 [2, -5, 4]])
```

Now I would like to (sort/get the maximum/do argsort/argmax/ etc) this array in such a way that it first compares the first column. If the first column is equal, it compares the second column, and then the third. So this means for our example:

```py
# max like python: max(x.tolist())
np.tuple_like_amax(x) = np.array([2, -5, 4])
# argmax does't have python equivalent, but something like: [i for i, e in enumerate(x.tolist()) if e == max(x.tolist())][0]
np.tuple_like_argmax = 3

# sorting like python: sorted(x.tolist())
np.tuple_like_sort(x) = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0, 2.0], [2.0, -5.0, 0.333], [2.0, -5.0, 4.0]])

# argsort doesn't have python equivalent, but something like: sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: x[i].tolist())
np.tuple_like_argsort(x) = np.array([0, 2, 1, 3])
```

This is exactly the way how python compares tuples (so actually just calling `max(x.tolist())` does the trick here for max. It does feel however like a time-and-memory waste to first convert the array to a python list, and in addition I would like to use things like argmax, sort and all the other great numpy functions.

So just to be clear, I'm not interested in python code that mimics an argmax, but for something that achieves this without converting the lists to python lists.

**Found so far:**

`np.sort` seems to work on structured arrays when `order=` is given. It does feel to me that creating a structured array and then using this method is overkill. Also, `argmax` doesn't seem to support this, meaning that one would have to use `argsort`, which has a much higher complexity.

Comment: How about `np.max(x,axis=0)`? This will return the max of every column. You can specify the `axis` in many `numpy` function to indicate in which dimension you like to apply the operation.

Comment: I’m aware of the functionality but I don’t see how it helps me in this case. Maybe I’m overlooking something, if so please let me know!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question completely. What do you mean by "if the first column is equal it compares the second column, and then third"? Could you provide the desired output e.g. for max and the 2d array you given as example?

Comment: Good point. Added!

Comment: @Tinu: Look at the output of `max(x.tolist())`: that is what he's looking for: the last row, because seen as a tuple, it would be the max in tuple logic (compare first element first, then break ties with second, etc.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a a so-called "lexicographic" max. The closest thing I'm aware of is `numpy.lexsort`, which sorts columns lexicographically, in a slightly weird way. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277143/sort-2d-numpy-array-lexicographically) for details. Since you want max, not sort, this isn't *quite* a duplicate of that IMO. But I bet some people here will disagree.

Comment: Thanks! That's very much what I'm looking for -- although you're right that it doesn't give the max, which is not the same (max is an `O(n)` operation, whereas sort an `O(n log(n))` -- and memory wise is `O(1)` vs `O(n)`... Still, as long as the arrays are not too large, this is probably the best solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I will focus only on finding the lexicographic `argmax` (the others: `max`, `argmin`, and `min` can be found trivially from `argmax`). In addition, unlike `np.argmax()`, we will return *all* rows that are at rank 0 (if there are duplicate rows), i.e. all the indices where the row is the lexicographic maximum.

The idea is that, for the "tuple-like order" desired here, the function is really:

- find all indices where the first column has the maximum;
- break ties with the places where the second column is max, under condition that the first column is max;
- etc., as long as there are ties to break (and more columns).

```
def ixmax(x, k=0, idx=None):
    col = x[idx, k] if idx is not None else x[:, k]
    z = np.where(col == col.max())[0]
    return z if idx is None else idx[z]

def lexargmax(x):
    idx = None
    for k in range(x.shape[1]):
        idx = ixmax(x, k, idx)
        if len(idx) < 2:
            break
    return idx
```

At first, I was worried that the explicit looping in Python would kill it. But it turns out that it is quite fast. In the case where there is no ties (more likely with independent `float` values, for instance), that returns immediately after a single `np.where(x[:, 0] == x[:, 0].max())`. Only in the case of ties do we need to look at the (much smaller) subset of rows that were tied. In unfavorable conditions (many repeated values in all columns), it is still ~100x or more than the partition method, and `O(log n)` faster than `lexsort()`, of course.

### Test 1: correctness

```
for i in range(1000):
    x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000, 8))
    found = lexargmax(x)
    assert lexargmax_by_sort(x) in found and np.unique(x[found], axis=0).shape[0] == 1
```

(where `lexargmark_by_sort` is `np.lexsort(x[:, ::-1].T)[-1]`)

### Test 2: speed

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100_000, 100))

a = %timeit -o lexargmax(x)
# 776 µs ± 313 ns per loop

b = %timeit -o lexargmax_by_sort(x)
# 507 ms ± 2.65 ms per loop
# b.average / a.average: 652
 
c = %timeit -o lexargmax_by_partition(x)
# 141 ms ± 2.38 ms
# c.average / a.average: 182
```

(where `lexargmark_by_partition` is based on @MadPhysicist very elegant idea:

```
def lexargmax_by_partition(x):
    view = np.ndarray(x.shape[0], dtype=[('', x.dtype)] * x.shape[1], buffer=x)
    return np.argpartition(view, -1)[-1]
```

)

After some more testing on various sizes, we get the following time measurements and performance ratios:

[image]

In the LHS plot, `lexargmax` is the group shown with `'o-'` and `lexargmax_by_partition` is the upper group of lines.

In the RHS plot, we just show the speed ratio.

Interestingly, `lexargmax_by_partition` execution time seems fairly independent of `m`, the number of columns, whereas our `lexargmax` depends a little bit on it. I believe that is reflecting the fact that, in this setting (purposeful collisions of max in each column), the more columns we have, the "deeper" we need to go when breaking ties.

### Previous (wrong) answer

To find the `argmax` of the row by lexicographic order, I was thinking you could do:

```
def lexmax(x):
    r = (2.0 ** np.arange(x.shape[1]))[::-1]
    return np.argmax(((x == x.max(axis=0)) * r).sum(axis=1))
```

Explanation:

- `x == x.max(axis=0)` (as an int) is 1 for each element that is equal to the column's max. In your example, it is (`astype(int)`):

  ```
  [[0 0 0]
    [1 0 0]
    [0 1 0]
    [1 0 1]]
  ```
- then we multiply by a column weight that is more than the sum of 1's on the right. Powers of two achieve that. We do it in `float` to address cases with more than 64 columns.

But this is **fatally flawed**: The positions of `max` in the second column should be considered only in the subset where the first column had the max value (to break the tie).

Other approaches including affine transformations of all columns so that we can sum them and find the max don't work either: if the max in column 0 is, say, `1.0`, and there is a second place at `0.999`, then we would have to know ahead of time that difference of `0.001` and make sure no combination of values from the columns to the right to sum up to overtake that difference. So, that's a dead end.

Comment: This will run into problems with a large number of columns and integer input

Comment: Yup, limited to 64 columns with `int64` as the type. But otherwise, it is `O(n)` (and very fast in fact).

Comment: ok, fixed. Using `float` now allows more columns.

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to bench mark this vs my partition solution?

Comment: Apologies: there is a bug in my logic (second column max should be subjugated to first column ismax be true). Figuring out if I can salvage this... In terms of timing, this is faster than partition, but who cares since it is wrong.

Comment: Very nice idea!  I like the creativeness (and it seems that numpy programming is often about that!). Don't make it into float, you'll loose accuracy when the numbers become too large, meaning that a 65 column result that differs in the last column will not be correct. On the other hand, 64 columns is plenty for most uses!

Comment: Hats off! I spent the past 30 minutes trying to find an example where `partition` would actually be faster, because indeed, gut feeling says that looping in python is a bad idea. But even with all numbers the same (the worst case looping), and replacing `col == col.max()` by `np.isclose(col, np.nanmax(col), atol=0, rtol=0, equal_nan=True)`, which does play nice with nan-values (sort at end, select if all values in column are nan -- will need some tweaking if `min()` is requested), your version remains much faster. And, added bonus, returns ALL args for the max, not just the first.

Comment: Actually: my comments about `nan` is false. Numpy (>1.14) adds `nan` to the end, so giving them the highest order in sorting. So looks to me like `np.isclose(col, col.max()), atol=0, rtol=0, equal_nan=True)` would replicate that (so any `nan` in the column will result in the max for that column being `nan`, effectively giving `nan` the highest value. `np.nanmax(col)` can then be used for minimum.

Comment: I still love @MadPhysicist's answer the best though. It uses two techniques that I had no idea about: this `view` he creates, and then `np.partition` and `np.argpartition`! Wow, super creative.

Comment: @PierreD. I actually like the explicit

Answer (score 2):

To sort a list by the contents of a row, you can use [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html). The only catch is that it sorts by the last element of the selected axis first:

```
index = np.lexsort(x.T[::-1])
```

OR

```
index = np.lexsort(x[:, ::-1].T)
```

This is "argsort". You can make it into "sort" by doing

```
x[index]
```

"min" and "max" can be done trivially by using the index:

```
xmin = x[index[0]]
xmax = x[index[-1]]
```

Alternatively, you can use a technique I suggested in one of my questions: [Sorting array of objects by row using custom dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64215263/2988730). The idea is to make each row into a structure that has a field for each element:

```
view = np.ndarray(x.shape[0], dtype=[('', x.dtype)] * x.shape[1], buffer=x)
```

You can sort the array in-place by operating on the view:

```
>>> view.sort()
>>> x
array([[ 1.   ,  2.   ,  3.   ],
       [ 1.   ,  4.   ,  2.   ],
       [ 2.   , -5.   ,  0.333],
       [ 2.   , -5.   ,  4.   ]])
```

That's because the [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor points to `x` as the original buffer.

You can not get [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html), [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), [`min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.min.html) and [`max`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.max.html) to work on the result. However, you can still get the min and max in `O(n)` time using my favorite function in all of numpy: [`np.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
view.partition([0, -1])
xmin = x[0]
xmax = x[-1]
```

You can use [`argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) on the array as well to get the indices of the desired elements:

```
index = view.argpartition([0, -1])[[0, -1]]
xmin = x[index[0]]
xmax = x[index[-1]]
```

Notice that both `sort` and `partition` have an `order` argument that you can use to rearrange the comparison of the columns.

Comment: Thanks! It solves half the problem. In large arrays I would prefer not to have to do a full sort (which is more expensive) in order to get the max -- but I agree that probably this is not available.

Comment: @Claude. Bear with me. I may have another alternative

Comment: @Claude. I found your O(n) solution for min and max

Comment: This is gorgeous. I didn't know about `partition` and `argpartition`! One small thing: I think you meant `np.argpartition(view, -1)[-1]` to find the maximum row index. On my version of `numpy` (1.19.2), `view.partition(k)` doesn't return anything and works in-place (affecting x). I still wonder about the complexity: `np.partition(view, -1)` appears fully sorted.

Comment: Very nice work, I love being introduced to other people's favourite numpy functions :) -- one small issue: `view.partition()` returns `None` (and partitions in place), so use `np.partition(view, 0)[0]`! Maybe good to mention in the answer  that the `view.partition` works regardless of whether you did a `view.sort` before.

Comment: @Claude: use `np.partition(view, -1)[-1]` instead (for `max`), as per my previous comment.

Comment: Yep @Pierre D, I just saw your message :) -- didn't get a notification until I posted :(. Numpy documentation claims that `np.partition` is `O(n)`. Check `np.partition(np.random.randint(100, size=(10, )), -1)` -- it certainly does not sort everything.

Comment: @Claude. Thanks for the catch. I fixed the return values

Comment: @PierreD. The array often appears fully sorted for small inputs. For large inputs, the asymptotic complexity is O(n). You are performing a binary search for the index, with exponentially decreasing segments that need to be inspected at each step. It's like quick sort, but you only recurse into one side of the pivot, never both.

Comment: yes indeed. A few decades ago, I wrote something related (in C of all things): a `kqsort(x, k)` to find the first `k` values, abandoning the rest of the sort. This one would be for a single value at index `k`.

Comment: ok, found a way that is faster. Also `O(n+m)`, but with constants that makes it about 150x faster on `np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100000,100))`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: despite my comment on speed, I still find this to be the most creative (and educational) solution. Really wonderful.

Comment: @PierreD. I appreciate the appreciation. While I agree that this solution is short and pretty cool, I like yours better for speed and practical maintenance.